# Change range for one y axis nvd3/d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am currently using the multiChart model and I have two different y Axes.  I would like to like to change both of the axes so that they start at 0 because currently they start at the smallest y data point.

I have tried doing the following

```
chart.yAxis1
tickFormat(d3.format(',.f'))
.domain([0,max_y]);
```

but that doesnt seem to work

and

```
.forceY ([0, max_y])
```

it tells me that there is no forceY function

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I'm having the same issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can force min and max values in NVD3 for line or bar charts, try as below:

```
chart.bars.forceY([0]);

chart.lines.forceY([0,100]);
```

Comment: This works on the line plus bar chart but does not seem to work on the multi chart.

Comment: There is a typo in this response, it should read `chart.lines.forceY([0, 100]);`. Edited. Useful for me. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

`.domain([0, max_y])` should be used on a [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) object, not an [axis object](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-axis).

So:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,max_y])
var yAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
```

This should work; if not, you should post what you have as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Hey, my code uses data points from a database so I'm not sure how I would be able to show you my graphs.
I tried doing 
var yscale1 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,400000]);
but I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'linear' of undefined. I am using nvd3 to make my graphs btw, not just d3.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) -> copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found that solves the problem is by adding yDomain1 or yDomain2 in the chart definition

For nvd3:

```
var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
    .yDomain1([-20, 80]) 
    .yDomain2([-50, 200])
```

For nvd3 AngularJS:

```
$scope.dashOptions = {
    chart : {
        type : 'multiChart',
        yDomain1:[-20, 80],
        yDomain2:[-50, 100],
```

Source:
[Solution by Alex. in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29434688/5437999)