# NVD3.js multichart with fixed x- and y-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis, nvd3.js

I´m using a NVD3.js multichart to display various data. Is it possible set a fixed range for the x- and y-axis. 
I´ve made a Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OLN87eIE21tImHktYIH6?p=preview

```
 var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range());
            chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
                  return d3.time.format('%H:%m')(new Date(d));
                });

            chart.yAxis1.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
            chart.yAxis2.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
            d3.select('#diagramChart svg')
            .datum(bpmData)
            .transition().duration(500).call(chart);
```

I´d like to set the x-axis from 00:00 to 23:59 and stop it from resizing when one data is deselected. Same with the y-axis, but with other values.
Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you're referencing an older version of nvd3 on plnkr. There is an documentation and a new version 1.7.x - many charts are using shared libraries since especially multiChart was buggy.
And you did no search really well, there are already some questions about this.

so for your question try

```
            chart
            .yDomain1([0,200])
            .yDomain2([0,10]);
```

I could not get s.th. like that working for xAxis. But i read not all is workin in multiChart if it works on line or bar or stacked area chart, so that could maybe the problem.

posts:

[nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal-chart-x-axis-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048454/nvd3-multi-bar-horizontal-chart-x-axis-domain)

[change-range-for-one-y-axis-nvd3-d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070238/change-range-for-one-y-axis-nvd3-d3)

[how-can-i-specify-a-domain-x-axis-in-nvd3-linechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887542/how-can-i-specify-a-domain-x-axis-in-nvd3-linechart)

UPDATE: thats part of my code on a multiChart which is running and in nvd3 1.7 (but could have som deprecated notation since I updated it from 1.1):

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
  .yDomain1([-20, 80]) 
  .yDomain2([-50, 200]) //important! works only with manual tickValues definiton (see chart1.yAxis2.tickValues([...]) !) 
  .margin({top: 30, right: 75, bottom: 40, left: 70}) //important for display of lable on y2Axis!
  ;

//chart option settings  
var options = {
    showControls: false,
    showLegend: true
}
chart1.options(options); 

d3.json(filepath, function(error, json) {
  if (error) {
    return console.warn(error);
  }
  var _inputdata = json.map(function(series) {
    series.values = series.values.map(function(d) {
      return { x: d[0], y: d[1] }
    });
    series.key = series.key.map(function(d) {
      return d[lang]
    });
  return series;
  });

  chart1.xAxis
    .axisLabel("Date")
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return (d3.time.format('%d.%m. %H:%M')(new Date(d))) })
    ;

  chart1.yAxis1
   .axisLabel('leftAxis')
   .axisLabelDistance(10)
   .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'))
   ;

  chart1.yAxis2
    .axisLabel('rightAxis')
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'))
    //(problem is, nvd3 does always tickValues of 20 and then jumps to tickVlaues of 50). 
    //not possible to set fixed steps of ticks like "y2ticks(10), workaround (-50 til 200):"
    .tickValues([-50,-25,0,25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200]) 
    ;

  d3.select('#chart_1').append("svg")
    .attr("id", "chart1")
    .attr("height", 500)
    .datum(_inputdata)
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .call(chart1)
    ;

  nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
    chart1.update();
  });

  //update chart to correct alignments of objects (e.g. wrapping o. elements) 
  chart1.update();

});
```

});

Comment: I´m sorry but this isn´t working either, give it a try on the plnker above. The version that is used is the one provided by plnker, but in my on project its not working either, even with den current version. I also saw the other posts but none seems to be working

Comment: hmm to sad it is not running. I posted some of my code as an update. Be aware, the part of `d3.json(...){ }` is using some variables/functions of global functions in my code.